# Postgresql daily backup

Tags: postgresql

What is the best strategies or practices to create a daily backup for a postgresql database in production environment.

postgres 8.4 & centos 6.3

Comment: It is better to migrate this to [dba stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If someone will close it as duplicate, it will have 5 different close reasons ^^ Please make screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostgreSQL wiki there's an entry on how to do it. Please check this url http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux and use those scripts and if you need any further info on how to use cron use this [blog post](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).

Another option/complement is to use the [WAL Archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html).

Comment: You can use this docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/unknownlighter/pgbackup/

Comment: I checked above URL (wiki) pg_backup_rotated.sh file is not in the particular directory  . what are the changes need to do to get the daily back up. 1st time I try to do, could you give some more details.

Comment: @Pirinthan you neeed to add a cron job. Check this site for some examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/